# MySQL ERROR: 'Unkown column' tablename.colname in 'on clause'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to join 2 tables to another table. I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT
desc_1.description,
desc_2.description,
Object.objID,
Item.itemID
FROM
Object,
Item 
INNER JOIN Foo desc_1 ON desc_1.descID = Object.objDescID
INNER JOIN Foo desc_2 ON desc_2.descID = Item.itemDescID;
```

However i get the following error:

```
ERROR 1054: Unkown column 'Object.objDescID' in 'on clause'
```

Desired Output:

```
description | description | objID | itemID |
------------+-------------+-------+--------+      
 "Daughter" |   "Shoes"   |   20  |   25   |
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? The column exists in the table i have checked spelling etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your query is what you want, then replace the `,` with `cross join`:

```
SELECT desc_1.description, desc_2.description,
       Object.objID, Item.itemID
FROM Object CROSS JOIN
     Item INNER JOIN
     Foo desc_1
     ON desc_1.descID = Object.objDescID INNER JOIN
     Foo desc_2
     ON desc_2.descID = Item.itemDescID;
```

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) even explains this, although I admit it is a bit hard to find:

> However, the precedence of the comma operator is less than of INNER
>   JOIN, CROSS JOIN, LEFT JOIN, and so on. If you mix comma joins with
>   the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the
>   form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur. Information
>   about dealing with this problem is given later in this section.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix legacy implicit join syntax and the explicit join syntax. Use

```
SELECT desc_1.description,
       desc_2.description,
       Object.objID,
       Item.itemID
FROM Object
INNER JOIN Item on { fill in the column that relate object and item }
INNER JOIN Foo desc_1 ON desc_1.descID = Object.objDescID
INNER JOIN Foo desc_2 ON desc_2.descID = Item.itemDescID;
```

Comment: Item and Object are not related. Object gets its description from Foo and so does Item. Object and Item are both related to Foo but not to each other.

Comment: Maybe you should add example data to your question along with the desired output.